# How to count frequency of each letter of word in qbasic or c language?

Tags: logic, qbasic

Successfully counted each letter but letter order can't display sequentially as in word.
For example- Input word-bbinood 
             Output=b2i1n1o2d1

Here my program in qbasic:

```
INPUT "Enter the string:", A$
n = LEN(A$)

FOR i = 97 TO 122

    FOR j = 1 TO n
        IF CHR$(i) = MID$(A$, j, 1) THEN
            count = count + 1
        END IF
    NEXT
    FOR j = 1 TO n
        IF (MID$(A$, j, 1) = CHR$(i)) THEN
            PRINT CHR$(i), count
            j = n
        END IF

    NEXT

    count = 0
NEXT
```

Comment: Can you reword your question? It's quite confusing to comprehend.

Comment: question is easy to understand- Input : bbinnod  then output should be in format : b2i1n2o1

Comment: @BinodThakur, it is not up to you to tell people that your question is easy to understand. If somebody asks you to explain your question better, just to it.

Comment: sorry guys i confess  i did  mistake. Well what question is counting frequency of each letter of word and letter order should be in same word letter.For example if input word is-bbinnod then output should be b2i1n2o1d1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here's code that should work in Qbasic.

```
DEFINT A-Z
DIM char(1 TO 255) AS STRING * 1
DIM outp(1 TO 255) AS STRING
INPUT "Type your string: ", inp$

'**** Comment out the following line if you want upper and lower cases
'**** treated separately:
inp$ = LCASE$(inp$)

FOR i = 1 TO LEN(inp$)
  char(i) = MID$(inp$, i, 1)
NEXT i

l = 0
FOR i = 1 TO LEN(inp$)
  k = 1
  FOR j = 1 TO i - 1
    IF char(j) = char(i) THEN GOTO skplet
  NEXT j
  l = l + 1
  FOR j = i + 1 TO LEN(inp$)
    IF char(j) = char(i) THEN k = k + 1
  NEXT j
  outp(l) = char(i) + LTRIM$(STR$(k))
skplet:
NEXT i

FOR i = 1 TO l
  PRINT outp(i);
NEXT i
```

Note that, as remarked in the comment, upper and lower case will be treated as the same letters as this answer stands.  If you want them to be treated separately, simply delete or comment out the `inp$ = LCASE$(inp$)`  line.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to answer this.

The first is a simple run-length encoding scheme, where the input `cabc` results in `c1 a1 b1 c1`. This has the benefit that you can often output things immediately with a fairly low memory requirement to boot:

```
input-string := Get-Input

(* nil is the representation of no characters here. *)
last-char := nil
count := 0

For Each (char c) In input-string
    If c = last-char Then
        count := count + 1
    Else
        If last-char = nil Then
            count := 1
            last-char := c
        Else
            Display last-char, count
            count := 1
            last-char := c
        End If
    End If
Loop
If count != 0 Then
    Display last-char, count
End If
```

The other solution I conceived will preserve the order and determine the counts of all unique letters in the string, yielding `c2 a1 b1` for an input of `cabc`. This solution is a bit more complex and requires more memory and often more execution time, but it results in more compact output due to the lack of repeated letters:

```
input-string := Get-Input

(* 26 is the number of letters a-z. *)
counts := Create-Array 26
order-string := ""

For Each (char c) In input-string
    i := Locate-Char order-string, c
    If i = 0 Then
        order-string := order-string + c
        counts [Length order-string] := 1
    Else
        counts [i] := counts [i] + 1
    End If
Loop

For i := 1 To (Length order-string)
    Display (Char-At order-string, i), counts [i]
Loop
```

The first should be straightforward to convert to QBASIC, but you might need to use the help file to learn about the `DIM` keyword and how to use it to create an array. This algorithm assumes that arrays start at 1, not 0.

Comment: @BinodThakur If my answer helped you, feel free to upvote and/or accept it. Good luck in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

suggest 2 arrays, each 26 (if only considering alphabetic letters) that array

```
size_t counts[26] = {0};
```

then a second array `

```
char order[26] = {'\0'};
```

then for each letter in the input string.

```
if( isalpha( str[i]) ) 
{ 
    letter = tolower( str[i];
    counts[ letter - 'a' ]++;
```

then loop through `order` if match found the do nothing, else replace '\0' with letter

printing out would be loop through order[] until either '\0' encountered or all elements examined.

At each order[] != '\0':

```
putc( order[ element ]);
printf( "%d", counts[ element-'\a' ] );
```

Comment: Sorry i didnot understand -my question is if input is : bbinnod then output should be: b2i1n2o1d1.

Comment: @BinodThakur,  I'm not going to write the code for you.  However, I did layout all the steps and some snips of code.